# NetworkX: Approximate/Inexact Subgraph Isomorphism For Undirected Weighted Graphs

Tags: python, networkx, subgraph, isomorphism

Given two graphs (A and B), I am trying to determine if there exists a subgraph of B that matches A given some threshold based on the difference in edge weights. That is, if I take the sum of the difference between each pair of associated edges, it will be below a specified threshold. The vertex labels are not consistent between A and B, so I am just relying on the edge weights.

A will be somewhat small (e.g. max 10) and B will be larger (e.g. max 200).

Comment: Please provide some code you tried and explain what does not work in this code, so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of these two packages may help:

The Graph Matching Toolbox in MATLAB "implements spectral graph matching with affine constraint (SMAC), optionally with kronecker bistochastic normalization". It states on the webpage that it "handles graphs of different sizes (subgraph matching)"
http://www.timotheecour.com/software/graph_matching/graph_matching.html

The algorithm used in the Graph Matching Toolbox in MATLAB is based on the algorithm described in the paper by Timothee Cour, Praveen Srinivasan, and Jianbo Shi titled Balanced Graph Matching. The paper was published in NIPS 2006.

In addition, there is a second toolkit called Graph Matching Toolkit (GMT) that seems like it might have support for error-tolerant subgraph matching, as it does support error-tolerant graph matching. Rather than using a spectral method, it has various methods of computing edit distance, and then it is my impression that it finds the best matching by giving the argmax of the minimum edit distance. If it doesn't explicitly support subgraph matching and you don't care about efficiency, you might just search all subgraphs of B and use GMT to try to find matches of those subgraphs in A. Or maybe you could just search a subset of the subgraphs of B.
http://www.fhnw.ch/wirtschaft/iwi/gmt

Unfortunately neither of these appear to be in Python, and they don't seem to support networkx's graph format either. But I believe you may be able to find a converter that will change the representation of the networkx graph's to something usable by these toolkits. Then you can run the toolkits and output your desired subgraph matchings.